# It takes a long time to insert into a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tAJ88') is not null
drop table #tAJ88



create table #tAJ88 (
       conv_raw_AJ88_ECO_key             int,
       case_id                                         numeric(14,0),
       account_key                              int,
       account_period_key                int,
       aj_number                                varchar(25),
       county_code                              varchar(25)
)




insert into #tAJ88(conv_raw_AJ88_ECO_key,account_key,account_period_key,aj_number,county_code)
select ac.conv_raw_AJ88_ECO_key,a.account_key, ap.account_period_key, ac.aj_number, ac.county_code
from [Conv].[dbo].[conv_raw_AJ88_ECO] ac
inner join [IT].[dbo].[entity_identifier] ei on ei.identifier_value = ac.account_number
                                                                                                       and ei.identifier_type_key = @MITS
inner join [IT].[dbo].[account_x_entity_id] axe on axe.entity_identifier_key = ei.entity_identifier_key
inner join [IT].[dbo].[account] a on a.account_key = axe.account_key
                                                                                         and a.account_type_key = (select account_type_key from [IT].[dbo].[r_account_type] where code = ac.tax_type)
inner join [IT].[dbo].[account_period] ap on ap.account_key = a.account_key 
                                                                                                            and cnsd.NEXT_STEP_NAME not in ('A','B')
where  (convert(datetime, substring(ac.periods,4,4) + '-' + substring(ac.periods,1,2) + '-01' ) >= ap.period_begin_dt and convert(datetime, substring(ac.periods,4,4) + '-' + substring(ac.periods,1,2) + '-01' ) <= ap.period_end_dt)
and len(rtrim(substring(ac.periods,4,4))) = 4
```

The query inserts the data from a select statement. The select statement itself only takes 1 second to run and only 1500 records appear in the select statement. However, when I try to insert into the temp table, I takes more than 10 minutes. I have never seen this issue before. Is this a tech issue where we don't have enough disk space or does it have to do with indexing which should not matter.

Comment: Could it be that the query returns more than 1500 results, but when running it, a limit is added by the sql client?

Comment: Look at the query execution plans for the two queries. The one for the select by itself. And the one for the insert ... select.

Comment: Kendra Little at sqlworkbooks.com had a webcast a few weeks ago highlighting an issue in MSSQL where updates to temp tables that are created within the same scope in a stored procedure make a disk IO access for every row inserted.  You didn't say specifically, but if you are running this as a stored procedure, she outlined a fix where can wrap the insert into a sp_executesql command in order to change its scope and avoid this huge slow down issue.

Comment: @RobertSievers sounds interesting. Is there a link?

Comment: Regarding this issue though I second the request for execution plans.

Comment: @MartinSmith  It has been recent enough that she hasn't put it on the site yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are having contention in tempdb?  You can read about it here from Paul Randal: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/

Have you tried doing this insert, but instead create a real table and do the insert?  That would give you a clue if it was tempdb or not.